The curious gap in time cost for QKV computation in LLM inference
I use Nsight System to profile the LLM inference process in HuggingFace Transformers framework. I observe that time for q_proj, k_proj and v_proj varies significantly. As far as I know, the Q, K matrix is in the same dimension. What causes this result?
My hardware is Nvidia H800.
The following pictures are my Nsight output.



Have you clicked on the q_proj range to see its dependencies? You could also use the Stats Systems to perform some analysis on all occurrences of q_proj and k_proj to see if the average time for each range is similar to what the screenshot shows, or if this is an outlier.
